# How to use node.js with ArcGIS Web AppBuilder to list files in a widget

Tags: arcgis-web-appbuilder, node-js

I have built an ArcGIS Web AppBuilder
and a custom popup (widget.js). My goal is to list every file in a specific directory (in 'wwwroot' folder) to the popup user.

I didn't find any built-in methods, so I'm attempting to use node.js.
I installed node glob lib into my app:
    `npm install --prefix` `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\WABCustomApp\libs glob`
(first I tried to install only glob module in the dir, that I copied all nodejs dependencies for another try.)
I configured init.js to load this libary:
    `window.path + 'libs/nodejs/node_modules/npm/node_modules/glob/glob.js'`

And received the following error:
`Uncaught ReferenceError: module is not defined at glob.js:41`

How would you make Web AppBuilder work with nodejs?

If you wouldn't use this approach, what would you suggest for listing dirs in popups?

Comment: Are you wanting to display the directories on the SERVER, or directories on the CLIENT who has opened the web app? My guess is the server as you're talking wwwroot...but I dont know why you'd want your webapp to show files on the server.... seems dangerous.

Comment: I've also modified your question a little bit. You're talking about ArcGIS JavaScript API _AND_ Web AppBuilder. My take is you're using the WAB framework, and not so much the core ArcGIS JS API. As such, I've focused your question on WAB.

Comment: It's an internal system, so the security doesn't really matter. But thank's for mentioning.